# Returning NA inspite of valid values for mean function

Tags: r

I have the below function which tracks no. of miles run by a person in a city and in town on different days. I have 3 columns. Id(of a person) City Town. For same values of Id i have different values of miles ran ina city and in a town or NA if no miles were run. So I can have a Id=1 in multiple rows with different values for city and town corresponding to Id=1 and similarly for Id=2 and so on. I have 500 csv files one for each Id and now I need to calculate the mean of and combination of ids and below is my function.

```
milesmean <- function(directory, place, id = 1:500){
  if(directory == "miledata"){
    files <- list.files()
    data <- list()
    for (i in 1:500){
      data[[i]] = read.csv(files[[i]])
    }
    req.data <- vector("list", length = length(id))
    for(j in id){
      req.data[[j]] <- data[[j]]$place
    }
    mean(unlist(req.data), na.rm=TRUE)
  }
```

}

But when I call milesmean("miledata","city",1:10) I get NA as value and warning message

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(unlist(req.data), na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Any reason why? TIA. Note: I need to solve this only by looping not using lapply and other similar functions

Comment: The reason is given is the warning message : the `unlist(req.data)` final value is neither numeric nor logical. You should check that your data are not imported as `character` or `factor` when read from files.

Comment: But when I execute the inside code of reading files and then call the mean function it gives me a valid value only when I put it inside a func I get this warning message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

`req.data[[j]] <- data[[j]]$place`

is looking for a column literally called 'place' in your imported data.frame. If you wish to use the value supplied in the argument `place` you need to change it to:

`req.data[[j]] <- data[[j]][[place]]`

As there is no column called 'place' data becomes a list of NULLs, and these form a single NULL when unlisted, which is what causes the warning the mean function.

You can probably cut out the first loop too, leaving you with:

```
milesmean <- function(directory, place, id = 1:500){
  if(directory == "miledata"){
    files <- list.files()
    req.data <- vector("list", length = length(id))
    for(j in seq_along(id)){
      req.data[[j]] <-read.csv(files[[id[j]]])[[place]]
    }
    mean(unlist(req.data), na.rm=TRUE)
  }
}
```

to save reading files that you're not using for the mean.

Comment: @janos, I think it'll work fine as it is (admittedly haven't tested) because you can treat data.frames as lists for indexing (as I've done) or as matrices.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @Miff on executing the code,and calling the function like milesmean("miledata","city",1) I get the following error Error in files[[j]][[city]] : subscript out of bounds. Any reason why I could be getting this?

Comment: @Arin - have made a fix to the code for cases where id doesn't start at 1, but don't think that's your problem - I presume that there is a column called 'city' in your first file, otherwise you'll need to step through the code and see which line produces unexpected results.

Comment: @MIff Yes I do have column named City in all 500 files, as also mentioned in my original post. I fail to see how that could be the problem read.csv has header=TRUE as default so it should detect the names of cols in all file. Do you mean to say in consecutive files also it considers the colnames as data?

Comment: @Arin if the column's called 'City' you need to match the case exactly in the function call. No, I don't mean that read.csv() behaves differently - originally as the code was written it would fail if e.g. id=2:10 because it would try to allocate the first file read in to files[[2]], when  there's no file[[1]]. This was fixed by my edit.